# How do I find out the file descriptor of a file

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I'm asking because I'm trying to make a function in C for which I require the file descriptor of a file (can't use file pointers). I haven't found anything useful on here nor on google yet.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptors-and-Streams.html

Comment: There is no such thing as **the** file descriptor for a file. Each `open` call will get a file descriptor as a return value (there are also other APIs that can return file descriptors such as `dup`). So call `open` to get a file descriptor or clarify your question if you are somehow needing to get a file descriptor in another way.

Comment: When you say "a file", do you mean a disk file for which you have the name, or do you mean a `FILE*` resulting from a call to `fopen()`? If the latter, the answer is [`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html).

Comment: @kaylum has the basic explanation. You get a file descriptor as the return from opening a file with `open`. It is your responsibility to keep track of the file descriptors returned. If for some reason you lost track of one, the only way I can think of for finding a lost descriptor is a brute force `int i; for (i = 3; i < fd_max; i++) ...` and call something like `dup` for `dup2` or `fcntl` and check the return values.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand what a file descriptor is. A file descriptor doesn't exist until you create one for that file, I.e. with `open()`. And then save the value returned from open and that is your descriptor.

```
   int fd=open("file.txt",O_RDONLY);
   if(fd == -1){
   // error
   }
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html for details and more usage.

Comment: How exactly would that look syntactically?